# Appending multiple values to a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

`lst` is a list of strings.

I keep getting an error say append does not work for the string type. It makes sense that `word_dict[len(word)]` is a string, but I am not sure how else to append multiple values to the same key.

```
for word in lst:
    if len(word) == int(wordLength):
        if len(word) in word_dict:
            word_dict[len(word)] = word_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            word_dict[len(word)] = word

print word_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the value a list of words. `collections.defaultdict(list)` can do that automatically:

```
word_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

...

# Whether the key has anything associated with it or not
word_dict[whatever].append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no append function for the String class, and that's why you have an here.

See the String functions here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

To append strings, use +

```
string1 = "hi my name is: "
string2 = "ryan miller"
print string1 + string2
```

Append is used when merging lists.

So instead of:

```
word_dict[len(word)] = word_dict[len(word)].append(word)
```

Use:

```
word_dict[len(word)] = word_dict[len(word)] + word
```

Answer (score 0):

Only problem you have here is that you set the value to be a string, namely 'word'. The error is because you cannot append an element in a string, so the only thing you have to do is to make sure you set the value to be a list. You can append an element to a list.

> for word in lst:
>
> if len(word) == int(wordLength):
>
> ```
>    if len(word) in word_dict:
>
>        word_dict[len(word)] = word_dict[len(word)].append(word)
>
>    else:
>
>        word_dict[len(word)] = [word]
> ```
>
> print word_dict